# Google Analytics is not tracking every page

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Google analytics is installed on my website. My website is built using Wordpress and using the plugin "Insert Headers and Footers" I pasted the code from Google Analytics. I can confirm that it works on *some* pages, but not all.

The website is an e-commerce store so not having the tracking on every page is making it hard to establish funnels.

I realized my e-commerce data was not being tracked so I researched the issue and learned about Google Tag Assistant. I installed this add-on and sure enough, no tags are reporting back for some of my store pages.

The below screenshot is from the Google Analytics report from the Tag Assistant. It shows that no tags are set on my page https://www.californiabeardco.com/store/ or https://www.californiabeardco.com/product/beard-oil/

The main site is https://www.californiabeardco.com

Interestingly, the analytics seem to work on the homepage and the cart/checkout pages, but not the store/product pages.

I'm really not sure what to do, I thought that the insert headers and footers plugin would insert the analytics code onto every page on my site.

I appreciate any insight you may have to offer, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular event that isn't reporting that you are expecting to see?

Using the ['Google Analytics Debugger'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome extension, I can see that Google Analytics is initialized on each page and is reporting page views.[image: console output]

Answer (score 0):

I think you recently added Google Analytical Code.Give it some time and Google will fix this. I added it in one of my site and my problem was same as you. I waited for 1-2 weeks until it resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Why can You just paste Google code to footer.php ? Other problem can be ajax pagination but this also can be fixed by refresh code after every ajax request.

Ps. And yes, sometimes You just must wait and Google will start working. You can check page source - if there is google code then it will start working, if not - You make something wrong.